# Looking for a design pattern to define various tasks that make a set of API calls and taking action after

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, data-structures

For our android app, I'm looking for a design pattern to define tasks which are made up of a number of steps, each step is an api call (each a seperate class) and an action that is taken after each api call with the results..

I want to be able to easily define tasks in the future and also keep track of the tasks and numbers, be able to roll back and also continue the task progress after being halted for a reason (OS shutting down the activity or losing connection)

I've implemented something but it's very hacky and it takes forever to create a new task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a combination of the Builder and Command patterns.
Use the Builder pattern to perform the "steps" that define a Command (i.e. task).

[Builder](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternBuilder.aspx)

[Command](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternCommand.aspx)